# Count Occurrence of each letter in a loop and display with letter with the most number of occurences

Tags: java, loops

I'm having trouble in using this code I found on the net. my goal is to count the number of times a letter show and display the letter with the most occurrence and if there are 2 or more letters that occurred at the same number of times then they will both show up.

This is my current output:
 [Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEu43.jpg)

Here is the code i found on the net and working with:

```
public void fcount(String str)
{

int[] occurence = new int[255];
   // Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// str = scanner.nextLine();

// optional to put eveyting in uppercase
str = str.toUpperCase();
// convert to char
char[] digit = str.toCharArray();
// count
for(int i = 0; i < digit.length; i++)

    occurence[digit[i]]++;
// find max
int max = 0;           // max value
char maxValue = 0;      // max index
for(int i = 0; i < occurence.length; i++) 

    {
   // new max ?
   if(occurence[i] > max) {
      max = occurence[i];
      maxValue = (char) i;
   }
}
// result
System.out.println("Character used " + max + " times is: " + (char) maxValue);
   // return "";
}
```

And Here is the the loop where i'm using it:

```
public void calpha()
{

char startUpper = 'A';
String cones = null;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

    cones = Character.toString(startUpper);
    System.out.println(startUpper);

}
fcount(cones);

}
```

Comment: so what is the problem, the code is working as it should. You put "A" into `fcount` and it tells you, that "A" is used 1 time

Comment: @JohnnyAW
the loop iterates 12 times, so the output is: 
A
A
A
A..

so it should tell me that i used it 12 times

Comment: I think in the loop, what you actually wanted is to do: cones += startUpper.

Comment: You might want to do `cones += Character.toString(startUpper)` if you expect `cones` to contain 12 times "A".

Comment: @Zurc in this case you should concat your `String`. btw. why don't you simply put "AAAAAAA" into `fcount`? why do you use the loop?

Comment: @BOND 

thanks! that made the trick! :)

Comment: @Gaël
thanks! that made the trick!

Comment: @JohnnyAW
that is only part of the program i'm working with. The program i'm working with deals with image processing and uses 12 frames. the program runs an algo for each frame and predicting what letter it might be... so i can't just put "AAAAAAAAA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in you loop:

```
cones = Character.toString(startUpper);
```

You are just re-assigning the value of `cones`, so `fcount` receives a string containing only the last character.

A solution is

```
cones += Character.toString(startUpper);
```

Comment: I apologize to JohnnyAW and BOND, who commented before I posted my answer. I didn't reload the page, so I didn't see your comments

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in your `int[] occurence = new int[255];` statement and usage: `occurence[digit[i]]++` may lead to `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since char type is up to 2^16

Comment: I guess function assumes input (`str`) contains only ASCII characters (i.e. up to 128 different values.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can not deal with non-ANSII characters. Mine does.

```
import java.util.*;

class Problem {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final String input = "I see trees outside of my window.".replace(" ", "");

        final List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>(input.length());
        for (final char c : input.toCharArray()) {
            chars.add(c);
        }

        int maxFreq = 0;
        final Set<Character> mostFrequentChars = new HashSet<>();
        for(final char c : chars) {
            final int freq = Collections.frequency(chars, c);
            if (freq > maxFreq) {
                mostFrequentChars.clear();
                mostFrequentChars.add(c);
                maxFreq = freq;
            }
            else {
                if (freq == maxFreq) {
                    mostFrequentChars.add(c);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Character c : mostFrequentChars) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    char startUpper = 'A';
    String cones = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        cones += Character.toString(startUpper);
        System.out.println(startUpper);
    }
    fcount(cones);
}

public static void fcount(String str) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    HashSet<Character> letters = new HashSet<Character>();
    str = str.toUpperCase();
    //Assume that string str minimium has 1 char
    int max = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int newValue = 1;
        if (hashMap.containsKey(str.charAt(i))) {
            newValue = hashMap.get(str.charAt(i)) + 1;
            hashMap.put(str.charAt(i), newValue);

            if (newValue>=max) {
                max = newValue; 
                letters.add(str.charAt(i));
            }
        } else {
            hashMap.put(str.charAt(i), newValue);
        }           
    }

    System.out.println("Character used " + max + " times is: " + Arrays.toString(letters.toArray()));
    // return "";
}
```